# Modifying MMS to remove delete functionality?

Tags: android

I am an experienced c/c++/php programmer. I'm new to Java and Android.  To get my learning kickstarted, I would like to modify the mms source code to remove the ability to delete text messages (My kids, ages 12 and 14,  have android phones, and knowing that they can't delete text messages should help to keep their conversations clean!). More specifically, I want to modify the mms code so that you need a pin to delete messages.  All of our phones are rooted, so replacing the entire app if need be isn't a problem.

Modifying/creating the source is no problem, my question is more a matter of the correct way to do it.  Does android or provide a way to "intercept" that a user has chosen to delete a text message, so that I can patch my own handling code in a separate external app? Or do I need to directly modify and build the mms source code and replace it on the target device to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

You would have to modify the exist [MMS](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#dpDz7Q08o9c/&q=MMS.git) app and remove the delete functionality. Specifically in the [ConversationList](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#dpDz7Q08o9c/src/com/android/mms/ui/ConversationList.java&q=delete&exact_package=git://android.git.kernel.org/platform/packages/apps/Mms.git) and remove delete from the menu.

Also, there is nothing stopping them from downloading another MMS app from the Market that will still let them delete texts.

Comment: Sure you can stop them...rip out the market app while you are at it!  This has the added benefit of stopping the kids from racking up a huge bill for paid apps.

Comment: But don't the 3rd party MMS apps (the ones that do true SMS, not through an Internet gateway) use intents from the original MMS app to provide funtionallity?  Isn't this what sandboxes applications from eachother?

Comment: No. They are listening for SMS (with android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED) just the like the regular app and do something special when one comes in. From my experience with an external SMS app, the notification from the baseline app still appeared in the notification bar. Your best option might be to install an sms logger, that backs up the sms. So even if they delete it you will still have a copy. Check out the SMS samples at http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/os/index.html. The SMS app works the same way.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need to modify the Android Platform source directly.

[Intents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) provide a way to "intercept" various user actions and route them to external apps.  However if multiple apps can handle an intent, the user is allowed to pick which one to use (a bad thing in your case).  Even if you wrote a custom SMS/MMS app for receiving/sending messages, the user would still be able to use the default app.

Comment: Maybe I could make a separate app which uses the original MMS app's intents to make a backup of the mms information and restore entries automatically if they are deleted from the original mms app?  Shouldn't this also protect against using 3rd party apps?